# How to change field name in serializers in django

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a field country_id and country_name and i want to change the name for both fields in Django rest Framework

write now I'm getting this data

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "country_id": 1,
      "country_name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
      "country_id": 2,
      "country_name": "Aland Islands"
    } 
  ]
}
```

I have change in serializers.py file but didn't work for me

serializers.py

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('country_name')
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ('country_id', 'name')
```

In model

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'countries'
```

I want this data

```
 {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Afghanistan"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Aland Islands"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Geting this error: AttributeError at /v1/location/countries/
'CountrySerializer' object has no attribute 'country_name'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to change in your "serializers.py" file

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='country_name')
    id = serializers.CharField(source='country_id')
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

then you will get data like this

```
 {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Afghanistan"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Aland Islands"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Does the actual model field need to be present in the fields Meta attribute, or the fields that are declared in the serializer? Where is the documentation for that?

Comment: For write-able serializers, does the validated_data contain name and id, or country_name and country_id?